# How to get rid of "Call requires API level 26 (current min is 24)"?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

How can I tell `Android Studio (3.0.1)` not to display `API 26` functions in the IntelliSense? It's quite misleading. 
Why does it propose those functions if I cannot use them?

Example: if I use the `java.util.Date`, it tells me:

> 'Date(int, int, int)' is deprecated as of `API 16`: `Android 4.1 (Jelly Bean)`

And if I use `java.time.Localtime`, I get:

> Requires `API level 26` (current min is `API 24`)

Is my `gradle` correct? I want the app to run on `Android 7.0` max.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx.xxx.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.8'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'io.paperdb:paperdb:2.6'
    implementation 'com.github.yukuku:ambilwarna:2.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> Date(int, int, int)' is deprecated as of API 16

*deprecated* but you can still *use it*, just means there may be a *better* way to do it.

> I want the app to run on Android 7.0 max.

Nougat Version 7.0 – 7.1.2, API 24 – 25

You can test which `API` the device is running, and so don't run more advanced commands on older devices which would otherwise crash them. This SDK_INT is available since `Donut` (`Android 1.6 / API4`).

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)

Change your build.gradle **to only use `API 24`**:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    //each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.
    //buildToolsVersion "24.0.1" //minimum supported version (26.0.2) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.1
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 24
    }
    dependencies {
        //you don't need these with support:design
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.0'

        implementation 'com.android.support:design:24+' //26 for AS 3 ?
    }
```

## Notes

(The `compile` configuration is now `deprecated` and should be replaced by `implementation` or `API`.)
See [support-library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index.html).
`compileSdkVersion` was the main point for your question. I did what you asked for, but it is common practice to compile as high as is available (`compileSdkVersion`) and minimum as low as works to support more devices (`minSdkVersion`).

Answer (score 0):

I have made a Java class and found solution after

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
{
    createChannels();
}
```

`createChannels` is my method.